# Order of BehaviorSubject elements is reversing expected output

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following code that is creating events that are in cases explained below, emitted back to front:

```
var feed = new Subject<double>();
var levels = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(new[] { 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0 });

levels
    .Select(thresholds => feed
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
        .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
        .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
        .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
    .Switch()
    .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Threshold)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));

feed.OnNext(520.0);
feed.OnNext(400.0);
feed.OnNext(450.0);
feed.OnNext(650.0);
```

Crossover detection extension is below:

```
public static class ThresholdExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> GetCrossovers(this double[] self, double previous, double current)
    {
        return self
            .Where(level => level >= previous && level <= current || level <= previous && level >= current);
    }
}
```

The first 2 emitted objects are in order, the 2nd emitted objects are backward

```
// the order of first 2 emitted objects should be reversed
{"Threshold":400.0,"Previous":520.0,"Current":400.0,"SlopeDirection":-1}
{"Threshold":500.0,"Previous":520.0,"Current":400.0,"SlopeDirection":-1}

// the below ordered is OK
{"Threshold":400.0,"Previous":400.0,"Current":450.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
{"Threshold":500.0,"Previous":450.0,"Current":650.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
{"Threshold":600.0,"Previous":450.0,"Current":650.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
```

The reversed output of the first 2 elements is to do with the ordering of the levels `BehaviorSubject` - but reversing this order would then cause the last 3 elements to be reversed.

How can I modify `DetectThresholds` to emit objects in the correct order as they are being crossed by the incoming feed?

Working example of the above is below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ThresholdCrossedEvent
    {
        public ThresholdCrossedEvent(double level, double previous, double current)
        {

            Threshold = level;
            Previous = previous;
            Current = current;
        }

        public double Threshold { get; set; }
        public double Previous { get; set; }
        public double Current { get; set; }
        public int SlopeDirection => Current >= Previous ? 1 : -1;
    }

    public static class ThresholdExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<double> GetCrossovers(this double[] self, double previous, double current)
        {
            return self
                .Where(level => level >= previous && level <= current || level <= previous && level >= current);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var feed = new Subject<double>();
            var levels = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(new[] { 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0 });

            levels
                .Select(thresholds => feed
                    .Buffer(2, 1)
                    .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
                    .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
                    .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
                    .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
                .Switch()
                .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Threshold)
                .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));

            feed.OnNext(520.0);
            feed.OnNext(400.0);
            feed.OnNext(450.0);
            feed.OnNext(650.0);            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi morleyc. Sorry for the downvote. I found the provided example to be needlessly cumbersome because of the similarity of the values. There are a bunch of numbers starting with `415` and differing only on their decimal part. To make matters worse this part is not consistently represented. It is `415.80` in one place, `415.8` in another. Trying to keep in my memory what is important, and ignore what is noise, become too much of a challenge for my mental abilities, and that's the basis for the downvote. It just reflects my personal inability to grasp the essence of this question.

Comment: Hi @Theodor, please don't be sorry, your points are totally valid and on review I agree. Thank you for the feedback I have learnt from this and tried to focus in removing the bloat.

Comment: Now it's much better, but still the query is a bit too complex for me. FYI I revoked my downvote.

Comment: Thanks Theodor - I managed to fix it and posted the answer, a good kick of a downvote and context of what I needed to fix was instrumental in taking a second look with a fresh head. Thank you for the time to look I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to to order the crossovers `LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]).OrderByWithDirection(x => x, x[0] > x[1])` with the below:

```
static class OrderByExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
           (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
            bool descending)
    {
        return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                          : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
        (this IQueryable<TSource> source,
         Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
         bool descending)
    {
        return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                          : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
}

levels
    .Select(thresholds => feed
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
        .Select(x => new {
                       LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]).OrderByWithDirection(x => x, x[0] > x[1]),
                       Previous = x[0],
                       Current = x[1] })                    
        .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
        .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
     .Switch()
     .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Threshold)
     .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
```

Using levels of `{ 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0 }` the output is now correct:

```
{"Threshold":500.0,"Previous":520.0,"Current":400.0,"SlopeDirection":-1}
{"Threshold":400.0,"Previous":520.0,"Current":400.0,"SlopeDirection":-1}
{"Threshold":500.0,"Previous":450.0,"Current":750.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
{"Threshold":600.0,"Previous":450.0,"Current":750.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
{"Threshold":700.0,"Previous":450.0,"Current":750.0,"SlopeDirection":1}
```

And example below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ThresholdCrossedEvent
    {
        public ThresholdCrossedEvent(double level, double previous, double current)
        {

            Threshold = level;
            Previous = previous;
            Current = current;
        }

        public double Threshold { get; set; }
        public double Previous { get; set; }
        public double Current { get; set; }
        public int SlopeDirection => Current >= Previous ? 1 : -1;
    }

    public static class ThresholdExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<double> GetCrossovers(this double[] self, double previous, double current)
        {
            return self
                .Where(level => level >= previous && level <= current || level <= previous && level >= current);
        }
    }

    static class OrderByExtensions
    {
        public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
               (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
                bool descending)
        {
            return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                              : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
        }

        public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
            (this IQueryable<TSource> source,
             Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
             bool descending)
        {
            return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                              : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var feed = new Subject<double>();
            var levels = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(new[] { 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0 });

            levels
                .Select(thresholds => feed
                    .Buffer(2, 1)
                    .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
                    .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]).OrderByWithDirection(x => x, x[0] > x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })                    
                    .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
                    .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
                .Switch()
                .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Threshold)
                .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));

            feed.OnNext(520.0);
            feed.OnNext(400.0);
            feed.OnNext(450.0);
            feed.OnNext(750.0);            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```